# What are the physical limitations of a SSD drive for long term cold storage?

Tags: ssd

As I understand it, SSD drives do not suffer mechanical failures, but are subject to a finite number of writes before failing.  I have stored mechanical drives for 5+ years and have been able to recall data.

QUESTIONS

If an SSD device is used for long term cold storage (disconnected and put in a safe for many years): What are the dominant [factors](https://www.anandtech.com/show/9248/the-truth-about-ssd-data-retention) that would limit how many years a SSD device remain in cold storage and return data?  I am concerned that storing data for 3-10 years risks losing data.

Is there any quantitative measurement that can be performed to determine if my cold storage SSDs are at risk of data loss?

Comment: I believe flash memory does have a retention period. The flash memory on microcontrollers is rated for 20 years I believe. I don't know about SSDs. That reminds me...I have to boot up my old Playstation memory cards and re-save the files...just in case.

Comment: https://www.extremetech.com/computing/205382-ssds-can-lose-data-in-as-little-as-7-days-without-power

Comment: Trapped charge in the NAND cells slowly leaks out in a (strongly) temperature dependent fashion.  How long a drive will retain data depends on the rate at which its cells leak charge and how robust its error correction is.  You are probably not going to be able to get this information for a consumer SSD, but if designing a product it is something you would be aware of.

Comment: Have you asked the manufacturer of your drives? They should be able to provide you the data. What is "cold"?